# How to create a SQL query with a result as JSON object and avoid duplicate entries (DISTINCT)

Tags: mysql, sql, json, group-by, distinct

I create a JSON object with a MySQL query. But unfortunately the `INNER JOINS` give me duplicate entries. How can I avoid these duplicate entries in my json object?

```
SELECT
  CONCAT("{",
  CONCAT("\"count\":" , g.count, ","),
  CONCAT("\"round\":" , g.round, ","),
  CONCAT("\"user\":", "[",
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT("{"),
    CONCAT("\"game_id\":" , gd.id, ","),
    CONCAT("\"user_id\":" , gd.user_id, ","),
    CONCAT("\"username\":" '"', u.username ,'"' ""),
    CONCAT("}")
  )
  ,"]")
,"}")
AS json FROM game_data gd
  INNER JOIN games g ON
    g.id = gd.game_id
  INNER JOIN user u ON
    u.id = gd.user_id
  INNER JOIN games_player gp ON
    gp.user_id = u.id
WHERE gd.game_id = 1234
```

I tried it with `GROUP BY`. Then I get the correct number, but each in its own json object.

```
WHERE gd.game_id = 1234
GROUP BY gd.player_id
```

How do I get the Distingt in my GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: Why aren't you using [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) and [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)? We are now in a post-MySQL 5.6 era, since that product has passed [its end-of-life](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql). So all currently supported branches of MySQL support JSON functions.

Comment: That said, I assume you are getting the duplicates because of the join to `game_player`. If there are multiple rows in that table per user, then it will cause the results to be multiplied. But `game_player` doesn't appear to be used in your JSON document, so I don't know why you're joining to it.

Comment: In any case, you should `GROUP BY gd.game_id`, not player_id.